# Allowing Implicit OAuth without scope - IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

**Hi,**

I created identityServer4 for securing our APIs. We want to allow one of our clients to connect without sending the scope parameter.

Currently, he can log in by sending query parameters as the following:
https://IP/connect/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=2b62b08868144d68bdd6112d1933b945&state=xyz&scope=general&redirect_uri=https://IP/Test

If he sends the request without scope the server throws invalid scope error.

Below is the declaration of the client

> ```
>  new Client
>  {
>    ClientId="2b62b08868144d68bdd6112d1933b945",
>    ClientName = "Client 2",
>    ClientSecrets = new [] { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
>    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ImplicitAndClientCredentials,
>    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
>    RedirectUris = { Settings.RedirectURL },
>    RequireClientSecret = false,
>    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { Settings.PostLogoutRedirectUris },
>    AllowedScopes = { "general" },
>    RequirePkce = true,
>    AllowRememberConsent = true,
>    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
>    Enabled = true,
>    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true
>   }
> ```

Comment: can you clarify a bit? did you remove `AllowedScopes = { "general" }` from client and then send a request with no scope?

Comment: Yes, but it is throwing invalid scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope is required on authorize endpoint, here is the doc ref:
https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html?highlight=Scope#authorize-endpoint

This feature might be considered in future on IDS4 Ref: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4556#issuecomment-654593955

Answer (score 1):

With OpenID Connect the openid scope is a required scope, all other scopes are optional. It represents the IDToken, that is mandatory.